# Convert csv tree structure to json

Tags: json, excel, csv, tree

I have a large excel document (2000+ lines) that uses the cells to specify a tree structure and I would like to parse that into a .json file. The excel-exported .csv document is formatted as follows, where in the excel file a comma would be an empty cell:

> Layer1category1,,,,,
>
> ,Layer2category,,,,
>
> ...
>
> ,,,,Layer5category1,
>
> ,,,,,item1
>
> ,,,,,item2
>
> ,,,,Layer5category2,
>
> ,,,,,item1
>
> ,,,Layer4category2,,
>
> ...
>
> Layer1category2,,,,,
>
> ...
>
> Layer1category8,,,,,  // this is the last category in the uppermost layer

In summary, Layer *n* categories are prefaced with *n-1* commas and followed by *6-n* commas, and rows prefaced with 5 commas are the final layer, which is in the format of a string and has many fields other than its name.

I would like this to be converted to a .json file similar to the following. I use "name" because aside from a name each field is also tied to a lot of statistics that also needs to go into the json file.

```
{"name" : "Layer1category1",
 "children": [
    {"name" : "Layer2category1",
     "children" : [
        {"name" : "Layer3category1"
         "children" : [ 
            ...
                    {"name" : "Layer5category1",
                     "children" : [{"name" : "item1"}, {"name" : "item2"}],}
                    {"name" : "Layer5category2",
                     "children" : [{"name" : "item1"}],}
                {"name" : "Layer4category2",
                 "children" : [
                ...
                ]}
"name" : "Layer1category2",
"children" : [ ... ]
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can approach this? The csv to json converters I have found do not support multi-layered structures. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue and wrote simple php script:

Input

```
Level I,Level II,Level III,Level IV,Level V,Level VI,Level VII,Level VIII,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Role Profile,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,Development,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,Security,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,Cloud,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,Cloud technologies,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,IaaS,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,Amazon Web Service (AWS),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,Microsoft Azure,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,Google Compute Engine (GCE),,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,OpenStack,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Output

```
{
 "Role Profile":{
  "Development":{
   "Security":{},
   "Cloud":{
    "Cloud technologies":{
     "IaaS":{
      "Amazon Web Service (AWS)":{},
      "Microsoft Azure":{},
      "Google Compute Engine (GCE)":{},
      "OpenStack":{}
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Code

```
<?php
$fn = "skills.csv"; // input file name
$hasHeader = true; // input file has header, we will skip first line
//
function appendItem( &$r, $lvl, $item ) {
    if ( $lvl ) {
        $lvl--;
        end( $r ); 
        appendItem( $r[key($r)], $lvl, $item );
    } else {
        $r[$item] = array(); 
    }
}

$r = array();
if ( ( $handle = fopen( $fn, "r" ) ) !== FALSE ) {
    $header = true;
    while ( ( $data = fgetcsv( $handle, 1000, "," ) ) !== FALSE ) {
        if ( $header and $hasHeader ) {
            $header = false;
        } else {
            $lvl = 0;
            foreach( $data as $dv ) {
                $v = trim( $dv );
                if ( $v ) {
                    appendItem( $r, $lvl, $v );
                    break;
                }
                $lvl++;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode( $r );
?>
```